# Could not open action6.h5py: UNKNOWN: NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open: action6.h5py : Access is denied. ; Input/output error

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, lstm, mediapipe

I got an error message when trying to load weight model in my machine learning app

```
model.load_weights('action6.h5py')
```

```
I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: SSE SSE2 SSE3 SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2023-10-21 19:06:17.395381: E tensorflow/tsl/platform/windows/windows_file_system.cc:363] ERROR: GetSymbolicLinkTarget cannot open file for \\?\c:\Users\ASUS\Python\Project\action6.h5py GetLastError: 5

2023-10-21 19:06:17.395635: W tensorflow/core/util/tensor_slice_reader.cc:97] Could not open action6.h5py: UNKNOWN: NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open: action6.h5py : Access is denied.
; Input/output error
```

How to fix it?